# Inverse 2d fourier transformation in MATLAB and OpenCV

Tags: matlab, opencv, image-processing, dft

I need to perform ifft but i've got different results with

```
dft(complexI, inverse, DFT_INVERSE | DFT_SCALE | DFT_REAL_OUTPUT);
```

in opencv and `ifft2` in matlab. 

`[0][0]` elements are equal but all others are not. So how does matlab scales the answer?

Comment: how "unequal" are they? by exactly a factor of pi or 2 ?

Comment: OpenCV output: https://i.gyazo.com/9c15d9e1e837c1b386a0421d93e649f4.png and matlab output: https://i.gyazo.com/dbbaf9dad5163ce78f7e1a403910d5f9.png

Comment: in matlab you should use `fftshift(ifft2(ifftshift( ... )))`  to shift zero-frequency component to center of spectrum and take care of the odd vs even pixel number cases...